# what's the difference between these two javascript expressions?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<a>` element that's supposed to run code and not redirect.

here are two examples of code which I believe should have the same effect, but it wont:

this works:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Works'); return false;" />
```

this won't:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return function() {alert('don't Work'); return false;};" />
```

Shouldn't they both do the same? 
Isn't the expression in the second attempt evaluated, calling the anonymous function and returning false?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second example defines a function and returns it. It never calls it.

```
onclick="return function() {alert('don\'t Work'); return false;}();"
```

If you call it (and fix the quoting error), then you would get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not valid javascript, as the `'` in `don't` prematurely ends the string. Replace `don't` by `does not` and see what happens.

And see Quentins answer on the fact you're not calling the function!

Answer (score 1):

The second line returns a function object, doesn't run it.
Instead the following runs:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Works'); return false;" >first link</a>
<a href="#" onclick="function x() {alert('don\'t Work'); return false;}; return x();" >second link</a>
```

Also, you need to escape ' character in "don't work".